# show loading div while Knockout computed function is running

Tags: asynchronous, knockout.js

a bit new to knockout just trying to figure out how to show a loading a div while a ko computed function is running.    I'm not quite sure exactly what I need maybe I need to use knockout extenders?

Anywhere here is the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/zf5k9rxq/10/

html

```
<input data-bind="value: val" />
<p><span data-bind="text: comp"></span>
</p>
<div data-bind="if: showloading">Loading...</div>
```

Javascript

```
function model() {
    var self = this;

    self.val = ko.observable("hello");
    self.showloading = ko.observable(true);

    this.comp = ko.computed(function () {
        //show loading
        this.showloading(true);

          // begin long running function
        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;
        while (i < 100000) {
            i++;
            j = 0;
            while (j < 80000) {
                j++;

            }
        }
        // end long running function

        //hide loading and return
        this.showloading(false);
        return this.val().toUpperCase();
    }, this);



}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});
```

Comment: Before you try to figure out how to use knockout, you should first review how asynchronous operations work.  Your "long running function" will  hold up everything, it's not even going to matter if you can get the div you want when you want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need `Show/Hide` div in computed may be its a mock up of ajax call i believe .

You can achieve it by something like this . Check the commented lines in below code to see minor changes I've made .

**view:**

```
<input data-bind="value: val" />
<p><span data-bind="text: compute,visible:!showloading()"></span></p> /*Toggling span visibility if loader is running*/
<div data-bind="if: showloading">Loading...</div>
```

**viewModel:**

```
function model() {
    var self = this;
    self.val = ko.observable("hello");
    self.showloading = ko.observable(true);
    self.compute = ko.observable();

    ko.computed(function () {
        var val = self.val(); //Creating a subscription 
        //show loading
        self.showloading(true);
        setTimeout(function () { //Delaying execution to show Loader
            self.showloading(false);
            self.compute(val ? val.toUpperCase() : val) //Assigning value to observable inside computed .
        }, 3000)
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new model());
});
```

PS:You can make use of subscribe too if you want to avoid computed.

working sample goes **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/zf5k9rxq/12/)**

Comment: yep thanks, subscription was what I needed. for my real project I have a live search on a table  and sometimes if there are a lot of rows it hangs for a second or two so I was just trying to show a little spinner at the top of the table.

Comment: You didn't really need a subscription or a computed. http://jsfiddle.net/zf5k9rxq/14/

Comment: @RoyJ agreed but i used computed/subscribe to show `loading` for  further changes , when made to input .  setTimeout does show loading but only onLoad .